# Telerik AJAX RadButton, how to click to open new tab without switching to it immediately?

Tags: asp.net, button, telerik

I have Telerik AJAX installed. I created a button on the page, by default, when I click, it's automatically leaving the current page and transfer to new page. If I set its Target = "_blank", it will open a new tab (Firefox) and switch to that new tab immediately.

I would like to know how to set it so that it will open the new tab, but won't switch to that new tab and remain on the current page?

```
RadButton btn = new RadButton();
btn.NavigationURL = "http://www.google.com";
btn.Target = "_blank";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the browser's functionality. Please check the below screenshot to how to disable this functionality in firefox.

[image]

Comment: Check or uncheck, same thing happen.

Comment: Sorry but i am not able to reproduce this issue? Can you please provide your code.

Comment: I have added in the code in my post. Please take a look. Thanks. If possible, would you please attach for me a sample project that works?